# Cannot see special characters on Polaris Office

Tags: special-chars, polaris-office

My mobile phone has Polaris Office default installed on it, but when I open some files I cannot see special characters, like "á", "à", "ç" etc., there is just a space character when it would have one of those special characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Palliatively, I installed [Kingsoft Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng), although it is so big for my device (it is about 13MB in size, and all my internal storage is just 180MB)... So I had to remove some apps to install it.

Well, it does the work well: show special characters without issues.

But I wait for a solution for Polaris Office...

Comment: Might be best to upvote and mark this answer as accepted to show that the issue is solved by using an alternative application.

Comment: But I would like to wait for a definitive solution, since it could save some bytes (an update, an hack or an add-on of Polaris Office would be smaller...).

Comment: Also I cannot upvote my own answer...